# VSTO how to keep Number Format when I apply a style to paragraph

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I want to change the style of paragraphs, and keep the Number Format

For begin like picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLTU8.png)

I write the code below to change style of Example A：

```
wdapp.Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Style = wdapp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
```

But the Number Format will be cleard (see picture Example A)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oTwO.png)

How can I do to keep the Number Format when I change style?

the example B is result what I want (see picture)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDweS.png)

In order to resolve problme, I try to use "ListFormat" to recover but useless

```
Dim bh = wdapp.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate
wdapp.Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Style = wdapp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
wdapp.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(ListTemplate:=bh)
```

Comment: The answer is here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-your-headings-ce24e028-4cb4-4d4a-bf25-fb2c61fc6585 First try it in Word so you can see how it works (what it will an will not do) - then do it using Interop.

Comment: @Fawlty  Thank you for your help. I know how to do in Word, However I want to adjust it in my add-in VSTO, so I have to know how to code.

Comment: Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior - This is what you get if you record a macro in Word, which is the best way of seeing how to reproduce what you want. I think you will need to loop each heading in the document to re-apply the numbering.